# PHP Oracle: oci_connect doesn't show error

Tags: php, oracle, error-handling, oracle-call-interface

There is an error in the `oci_connect` line. But my problem is that the error doesn't show in the page. Even if I put `$e = oci_error();` it will not be executed anymore to show the error. I tried try/catch but it didn't work either.

When I change the connection details to connect to another database it works. The connection details I use do work in SQL Developer.

```
$db='(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = '. $GLOBALS['HOST']. ')(PORT = '. $GLOBALS['PORT'] .'))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = '. $GLOBALS['SID'] . ')
)
)';
echo '<br>USERNAME: *'. $GLOBALS['USERNAME'] .'*';
echo '<br>PASSWORD: *'. $GLOBALS['PASSWORD'] .'*';
echo '<br>2 db: *'. $db .'*';
$conn = oci_connect($GLOBALS['USERNAME'], $GLOBALS['PASSWORD'], "$db");
echo 'success';
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really no errors being shown after trying changing the PHP.ini file setting to show all errors, then I have updated the Oracle Instant Client version.

First I check what Oracle version I'm using:

```
select * from v$version
where banner like 'Oracle%';
```

Output:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

After this I downloaded new Oracle Instant Client version Version 11.2.0.3.0 and set it to PATH and restarted server. Then it worked!